Problem with logarithm of tensor product of matrices
In the book of From Classical to Quantum Shannon Theory, in exercise 11.8.1, there is a property of logarithm of a tensor products of two matrices, defined as follows:
$$\log ( A \otimes B) = \log(A) \otimes I + I \otimes \log(B),$$
where $A,B$ are positive semi-definite operators. So I tried to use it on the following examples. Suppose $A$ and $B$ are density matrix defined as:
$$A = |0\rangle \langle 0 |,\\
B =  \omega_0 |0\rangle \langle 0 | + \omega_1 |1\rangle \langle 1|,$$
where both are constrained to density matrix requirement such as positive semi-definitess, same as the requirement in the exercise. When I apply the property for $A \otimes B$, I got different results as follows:
$$\log(A\otimes B) = \log(\omega_0) ( |0\rangle \langle 0 |_A \otimes |0\rangle \langle 0 |_B) + \log(\omega_1) ( |0\rangle \langle 0 |_A \otimes |1\rangle \langle 1 |_B).$$
Meanwhile, for the RHS, I obtained:
$$\log(A) \otimes I + I \otimes \log(B) = I \otimes \log(B) = \log(\omega_0) ( I \otimes |0\rangle \langle 0 |_B) + \log(\omega_1) ( I \otimes |1\rangle \langle 1 |_B),$$
since $\log(A)$ should be zero since its eigenvalue is 1. By inspecting their matrix alone, these two are not equal. I am wondering if I made any mistakes or the property has additional requirements?

You do you define $\log A$ if (at least) one of its eigenvalues is $0$?

...so the text is imprecise: It should read: "positive-definite operators" or so...

@TobiasFünke I didn't think about it carefully, but from a quick look the formula might very well still be correct if one assigns $-\infty$ to the zero eigenspaces of the operators. And it might well be that this is how the book defines the logarithm.

@NorbertSchuch Well, but then $\log A$ is not well-defined operator; $\infty$ is not a number (in standard analysis; i.e. to make sense of this you have to consider the extended real number line or so), and if $A|\varphi\rangle=0$, then $\log A|\varphi\rangle$ is un-defined, e.g. it has no finite norm etc.

@TobiasFünke As long as you treat this from a theoretical physicist's point of view, rather than mathematical physics or math, I'd say all is fine.

The problem is that you are using the logarithm incorrectly. If you are willing to allow for $\log(0)$, i.e., zero eigenvalues of your operators, then the correct definition must be $\log(0)=-\infty$. (While you use $\log(0)=0$, which is wrong regardless.)
These $-\infty$ terms will then show up in both of your equations. E.g., the first equation will read
\begin{align}
\log(A\otimes B) & = \log(\omega_0) ( |0\rangle \langle 0 |_A \otimes |0\rangle \langle 0 |_B) + \log(\omega_1) ( |0\rangle \langle 0 |_A \otimes |1\rangle \langle 1 |_B) \\[0.5ex] & \qquad\qquad\qquad+ 
\log(0) ( |0\rangle \langle 0 |_A \otimes |0\rangle \langle 0 |_B)
+
\log(0) ( |0\rangle \langle 0 |_A \otimes |1\rangle \langle 1 |_B)
\\[1.5ex]
& = \log(\omega_0) ( |0\rangle \langle 0 |_A \otimes |0\rangle \langle 0 |_B) + \log(\omega_1) ( |0\rangle \langle 0 |_A \otimes |1\rangle \langle 1 |_B) \\[0.5ex] & \qquad\qquad\qquad+ 
\log(0) ( |0\rangle \langle 0 |_A \otimes I_B)\ ,
\end{align}
and correspondingly for the right hand side. If you set $\log(0)=-\infty$ and use that $-\infty + x =-\infty$ (for finite $x$),you should find that both sides of the equation are the same.
Note that in the end, this is just a "classical" problem about numbers, since you can always work in the eigenbases of $A$ and $B$: Then, it just reads $\log(xy)=\log(x)+\log(y)$, which indeed also holds if $x$ or $y$ are zero if you adopt the convention $\log(0)=-\infty$.

One problem is that the logarithm $\log(A)$ of an operator $A$ is singular if $A$ has zero eigenvalues. E.g.
$$\log(|0\rangle\langle 0|)~=~\log(1)|0\rangle\langle 0|+\underbrace{\log(0)}_{=-\infty}(I-|0\rangle\langle 0|). $$
OP should as a minimum include these singular contributions in their calculation.
(More generally there might also potentially be issues with the branch cut of a complex logarithm: However in OP's case $A$ is assumed to be a positive semi-definite operator.)
